# Loading iframe inside UI dialog not working

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, iframe

I want to load and display iframe inside UI dialog box which will open by clicking on the elements those are generated dynamically through jQuery function.

Here is my code

HTML

```
<div id="eventContent" title="Event" style="display:none;">
<div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#map').html(event.map);
$('#eventContent').dialog({modal: true});
```

Where event.map is variable contains HTML string like given below and will change depending on which element user have clicked.

In short everything is dynamically generated data and HTML except above HTML code.

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d9927.782117587185!2d-0.1578822!3d51.5325589!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xc2ee490704162539!2sThe+Hub!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1452460618657" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

But this simply display string inside dialog, and i want loaded iframe inside it.

Comment: Need more information to provide complete solution. If I understand this, you have an image map, and when clicked, this should show the dialog containing an `iframe` where the source is set from the data involved in the click event. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more details about this project, this is what I would suggest. Assuming:

- Each Event has a map to it
- There exists a button or link that would launch the dialog
- the button or link would have an URL that is to be used for the `iframe`

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/9dk8jrqc/

**HTML**

```
<div id="eventContent" title="Event">
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>
<button id="show">
  Show Event
</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
var event = {
  "map": "https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d9927.782117587185!2d-0.1578822!3d51.5325589!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xc2ee490704162539!2sThe+Hub!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1452460618657"
};
$(function() {
  function showMap(url) {
    $('#eventContent div#map').html("");
    var frame = $("<iframe>", {
      width: 600,
      height: 450,
      frameborder: 0,
      allowfullscreen: true
    }).css("border", 0);
    frame.attr("src", url);
    frame.appendTo($("#eventContent div#map"));
    $('#eventContent').dialog("open");
  }
  $('#eventContent').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: 640,
    height: 480
  });
  $('#show').click(function() {
    showMap(event.map)
  });
});
```

To keep the solution dynamic, I suggest a function that collects the source to be used for the `iframe`. If there is an older `iframe`, from a previous action, it is cleared out. I then create an `iframe` dynamically, with the new source, and append it to the `#map`. Once this is done, I call open on the dialog.

You can use `showMap()` with many different click events and provide it with whatever URL you want shown in the `iframe`.

I might also suggest storing the URL or harvesting it from the link. For example, if each event had a link to the map like:

```
<a class="mapLink" href="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d9927.782117587185!2d-0.1578822!3d51.5325589!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xc2ee490704162539!2sThe+Hub!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1452460618657">Show Map</a>
```

You could gather this info and use it like so:

```
$(".mapLink").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  showMap($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

This could also be stored in buttons using `data-map-url` as an attribute too.

Answer (score 0):

Use Below code for your Problem.

```
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
</head>
<div id="terms" style="display:none;">
       <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d9927.782117587185!2d-0.1578822!3d51.5325589!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xc2ee490704162539!2sThe+Hub!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1452460618657" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<a id="showTerms" href="#">Show Terms &amp; Conditions</a>     
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#showTerms').click(function(){
             jQuery('#terms').dialog({modal:true});   
         });
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's also done by just creating temporary element through jQuery for fetching src from iframe HTML string, after that assign that src to iframe.

My HTML code

```
<div id="eventContent" title="Event" style="display:none;">
<div id="map"><iframe src=""></iframe></div>
</div>
```

jQuery code

```
$vars = $('<div>' + event.map + '</div>');
$srcs = $vars.children('iframe').attr('src');
$('#map iframe').attr('src',$srcs);
$('#eventContent').dialog({modal: true});
```

Optimized solution without generating iframe in hidden div or anything else.
That's all